# Flows - Possible To Use Loops with Null Collections?

Tags: flow, bulkification, bulk

I have a loop and inside the loop there is a decision and two assignments. The assignments should only be executed if the loop variable is null. However, if the collection is null then there is nothing to iterate over so the loop is skipped all together and nothing can be assigned and updated/created.

The only way I can get this to work is by removing the loop but that means that the process runs on a single record basis rather than on bulk. This is only really a problem when data uploads are performed but even so I'd still like to build something full proof.

Has anyone run in to this? ..This may be a design problem rather than a tech issue.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: In the past, I've initialized the collection with a 'junk' value (so it's not empty) and I then evaluate the collection to ask if size is greater than 1.  Then, if so, I remove the junk value and evaluate the rest.

Comment: Interesting, that would allow me to re route through the loop. Great thanks :)